# google's soa architecture - Aggregating content for google's web user interface

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, architecture, soa

When logged into to Google, the Google homepage links to multiple other services (e.g. Gmail, Play, Drive).

Q1) Is there a SOA pattern that describes the way that they loosely couple the UIs for each service, but at the same time also providing a standard menu bar, standard look and feel and single sign on across their applications?

Q2) Is there any documentation available that describes their architecture for linking the UI content?

**Edit**

I have taken a look with Firebug and it seems like there is a two way relationship between the menubar and the application.  The menubar has a link to each application, but each application also has the menu bar included.

I can relate this to the [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) UI, where an application can contribute to the application menu, but each menu lives in the context of the eclipse application which aggregates all the separate UI plugins.

So how does google do this in their UI?  It looks like there is some javascript wizardry going on, with the menu bar being injected into each application.

Comment: Not quite clear on what you are asking for here, could you please clarify or narrow it down? Your questions seem to focus on the user interface, but is this really what you want? Just running Firebug and tracing what files are downloaded and executed reveals a lot about where the user interface resources are loaded from. There are also several papers published (both by Google and others) on their single-sign on solution.

Comment: I agree with David, the questions are good candidates to write a book rather than to give a succint, to-the-point answer.

Comment: I have edited the question, hopefully it is a bit more precise now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell about Google, but I have worked on websites that do similar things. In one example, it was a website for a large real-estate agency that has offices around the world, the homepage (and other pages) include a carousel that displays content specific to the country, all the offices used different instances of the same CMS to manage their own contents.

What happens is that the CMS (.NET based) used custom and user controls (.ascx) files to render the final aspx page. These ascx files (for header, footer and carousel), all styles and javascript related to those files (put in a folder that can't be manipulated called _CSS and _JS as per our convention) are maintained centrally and then replicated to all local websites.

The CMS instance - specific to one country office - will then create its own pages but they all use these common headers and footers provided by the central application.

The last piece of the picture is to keep all of this in sync, you need some kind of an agent or service to propagate these common components to all servers and CMS instances in order to make sure that they all use the same controls, styles and javascript (styles and javascript could be referenced centrally but custom user control need to live within the application domain of the specific CMS at least for .NET). We used Repliweb for such tasks but I am not very familiar of its details.

From architectural point of view, I see it as some sort of a plugin architecture for the UI, so you are right to relate it to Eclipse architecture. The central CMS is an abstract type providing an Interface that specific site instances have to adhere to and implement it.

```
abstract class GoogleSite
{
    Control Header { get; set; }
    Control Footer { get; set; }

    public string Title { get { return "Default title"; } }

    public abstract void ProvideContents();
}

class Gmail: GoogleSite
{
    //still using same header and footer but Title is different
    override public string Title { get { return "Gmail"; } }

    public override void ProvideContents()
    {

    }
}


class GPlus: CentralCMS
{
    //Another CMS not overriding the title but Providing different contents
    public override void ProvideContents()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This is great.  Do you have an idea what the pattern is called, or could be called?  Maybe "UI Contribution Pattern"?  Once this pattern has a name, it will be easier to show approaches from other areas, for example:  [virgo snaps](http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/virgo-documentation-3.5.0.RELEASE/docs/snaps-guide/htmlsingle/virgo-snaps-guide.html), or [maven war overlay](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html)

Comment: I consider it a Plugin pattern. From MSDN: Plug-in pattern is a pattern that extends the behavior of a class by allowing extensions to plug into an abstract class that, in turn, plugs into a core class. This creates a new subclass that includes only the capabilities required in the specific context.

Comment: It should by possible to achieve the same end result with non-class based languages, so I wouldn't want to eliminate those approaches from the discussion.  How about "UI Plug-in pattern"?

Comment: "Plugin" should do imo, it's just that microsoft's definition is too narrow. You could say UI Plugin to clarify the context but it's still a plugin pattern at the end. In GoF book, it says to use "Plugin" pattern whenvever you have behaviors that require different implementation based on runtime environment, which seems to fit the bill here. The problem is just that frontend/ui community is not as keen on defining patterns as class-based language but at the end, the same concept applies (the same as Factory, Singleton and other patterns apply to javascript which is not a class-based language)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  I'll get another post on stackoverflow to try and put together a catalog of different UI Plugin implementations.  Thanks Kabaros.

Answer (score 3):

Google uses own [Closure Library](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/?hl=en) for the UI part:

> **What is the Closure Library?**
>
> The Closure Library is a broad, well-tested, modular, and
>   cross-browser JavaScript library. You can pull just what you need from
>   a large set of reusable UI widgets and controls, and from lower-level
>   utilities for DOM manipulation, server communication, animation, data
>   structures, unit testing, rich-text editing, and more.
>
> [...]
>
> **Who uses Closure Library?**
>
> Search, Gmail, Maps, Docs, Sites, Books,
>   Reader, Blogger, Calendar, Google+, Photos

https://developers.google.com/closure/library/?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

The hawt.io project has an interesting approach:

> hawtio is highly modular, so that it can discover exactly what services are inside a JVM and dynamically update the console to provide an interface to them.

The link is [here](http://hawt.io)